# Log4j & Kotlin - "Type Mismatch. Required: Message!, Found: String"

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, log4j, log4j2

My code is the following:

```kotlin
val logger = LogManager.getLogger()
logger.info { "some message" }
```

however, IntelliJ is reporting the following error:

```
Type Mismatch.
Required: Message!
Found: String
```

The `Logger` interface has the following two methods:

1. `fun Logger.info(messageSupplier: MessageSupplier)`
2. `fun Logger.info(messageSupplier: Supplier<?>)`

`MessageSupplier` is effectively a lambda of the form `() -> Message`, while `Supplier<?>` is effectively `() -> Any?`. The code `logger.info { "some message" }` should invoke method #2, however IntelliJ is checking it against method #1, which I don't want. Is there any way to make my exact code work? Even adding a custom extension function like below doesn't work:

```kotlin
fun Logger.info(messageSupplier: () -> Any?) {
    if (isEnabled(Level.INFO)) {
        logger.info(messageSupplier())
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use lambdas here to improve my application's performance, but as-is it doesn't seem like that is possible to do without adding code. I want to be able to simply call `logger.info { ... }` and have the result from my lambda be logged normally. Is the only way to create my own custom `Logger` interface?

I am using log4j version 2.21.1. It seems like these supplier objects were released in version 2.4, so I could downgrade to 2.3 to remove them, however that and all prior versions have vulnerabilities according to Maven. It also seems like these supplier objects are supposed to be deprecated in version 3.0, however 3.0.0-alpha1 does not have them removed. Does this mean that I'm basically SOL until they release version 3.0?

Comment: That's a Kotlin bug, as you can see [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22119). Currently Kotlin can't distinguish lambda parameters that differ only by the return type. Unfortunately, you have to add more code.